# Ember data not loading belongsto relationship using fixtures

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on a very basic ember app , but I can't seem to get it to display the belongsto model.

My user model:

```
News.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    items: DS.hasMany('News.Item')
});

News.User.FIXTURES = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Bobba_Fett",
        "items": [1,2]
    }]
```

My item model:

```
'use strict';

News.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    domain: DS.attr('string'),
    points: DS.attr('number'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('News.Comment'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('News.User')
});

News.Item.FIXTURES = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "This is story 1",
        "url": "http://google.com",
        "domain": "google.com",
        "points": 45,
        "comments": [1,2,3],
        "user_id": 1
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "This is another story",
        "url": "http://yahoo.com",
        "domain": "yahoo.com",
        "points": 30,
        "comments": [1,2,3],
        "user_id": 1
    }
]
```

My html ( the problem is that the username is not displaying, it is just blank ), Everything else displays fine:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
        <div class="row">
            <ul>
                {{#each itemList}}
                    <a href="upvote">&#x25B2;</a><a {{bindAttr href="url"}}>{{title}}</a> ({{domain}})<br />
            <small>{{points}} Ups -- submitted by {{user.username}}</small><br />
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in the `News.Item.FIXTURES` declaration, `"user_id"` should be named just `"user"`, because that is the name the attribute for the relationship got in the **Model** definition.

This should work:

```
News.Item.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "This is story 1",
        url: "http://google.com",
        domain: "google.com",
        points: 45,
        comment": [1,2,3],
        user: 1
    }, 
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "This is another story",
        url: "http://yahoo.com",
        domain: "yahoo.com",
        points: 30,
        comments: [1,2,3],
        user: 1
    }
];
```

EDIT: I don't know if you're still looking into this, but here is a working fiddle with your code, please note I had to add an empty model `News.Comments = DS.Model.extend({});` for it to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mftye/1/

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks, but when I make this change, I get the error "Cannot call method '_create' of undefined". Changing it back to user_id makes the error go away, but the data is still not populated.

Comment: That is weird, what version of ember / ember-data are you using? I am not getting any errors here

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful, but I'm not quite there yet, my handlebar view is a bit different than yours and the uname property of my user model still shows up blank. ( the user model itself displays as <emberdata:User...> ) example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bFPNb/2/

Comment: Damn I see now that I messed up the jsfiddle link... so to whom did I send your code?? I am trying to locate the correct working fiddle now, sorry about that

Comment: I forked your fiddle, changed the ember-data imported file in the external resources tab for a stable one and the problem seemed to go away. I don't recommend using the s3.amazonaws builds because there seem to be lots of things still in flux and sometimes you'll get unexpected behaviour. The link in the answer should be correct now

Comment: Here's an updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mftye/6/ Minor change really, but if people happen upon this and wonder why your solution doesn't appear to work, it's because of mime type errors caused by raw.github.com. The update fixes those errors.